# Adding a bullet point in Word 2003 causes Heading 3 to be applied

Tags: microsoft-word, formatting, styles, microsoft-word-2003

Without warning, Word 2003 is now turning any bullet point into Heading 3.

In addition, when I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> after typing my bullet point, the style is reverted back to Normal - whereas I would have expected it to continue with additional bullet points until I turn them off.

[image]

If I originally created the document on a different computer (running a different version of Word), then these issues are still present. This leads me to believe that it's probably not a stylesheet issue - more a Word configuration issue.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Are you using a style to insert bullets or are you clicking directly on the bullet icon?

Comment: I'm clicking directly on the bullet icon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the solution is, predictably, obvious:

1. Start Word
2. Click on **Help > Detect and Repair..**
3. Click on the "Start" button.

Once repaired, the bullet points will behave as you would expect.